# What is the difference between using @import and stacking CSS stylesheets?

Tags: css

What is the difference between

- @import; and
- stacking CSS stylesheets

in CSS?

They both appear to do the same thing. Are there any factual advantages (such as speed and clarity) of using one over another?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'stacking CSS stylesheets'?

Comment: Link a number of different external CSS stylesheets in the head section of an HTML document, just like a stack of plates.